# On click of TAB the focus should be on the next textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two textboxes and when TAB is pressed from one textbox it goes to another place instead of to the next textbox.

My code is:

```
   $(function () {

        $("input[id$=txt1]").bind('keydown',
        function (e) {
            if (e.which == 9) {
                // alert("hello");
                $("input[id$=txt2]").focus();
            }
        }
        );

    });
```

When I press tab for txt1 it should go to txt2 but it doesn't.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) and it will work

```
$("#txt1").bind('keydown',
function (e) {
    if (e.which == 9) {
        $("#txt2").focus();
        e.preventDefault()
        }
    }
);
```

BTW, its much better to use direct selectors with ids (#txt2 instead of input[id$=txt2]).

Comment: good idea. write some great code and disable it so it doesn't execute ever, wow! I am NOT down voting, though.

Comment: Disable it? What are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about your answer ***before*** your edit. Check that out.

Comment: Its just for aestethics, return false also works, you just need to put it as the last command.

Comment: @IvanCastellanos Direct selectors will not work when we use asp.net controls. Because the ids get changed

Comment: What the OP wants is default behavior, why prevent default and write code to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: True Kamal, didn't notice the dollar sign in the selector, my bad.

Comment: @IvanCastellanos No problem i just want to make sure that some other person reading this page must get some additional details

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to do any code here. You just have to assign tab indexes in a proper order.

For example:

```
<input type="text" value="a" tabindex="1" />
<input type="text" value="c" tabindex="3" />
<input type="text" value="b" tabindex="2" />
```

If you set a focus to "a", then push TAB, focus will move to "c", and then to "b".

See demo here: http://jsbin.com/epacop/2

Comment: Well, if this is a javascript question i think he wants a javascript answer. Plus: something that will work even with elements that do not support the tabindex attribute. Plus: Something that explains why his code doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe he didn't know about tabindex property. When you have a hammer, everything looks like nails to you.

Comment: When you are using a hammer, shouldn't you at least understand why the hammer is not working for you?

Comment: @IvanCastellanos yes but this is the best solution and you should know the best solution too.

Comment: Explain me why is the best solution? Because it doesn't requiere javascript? That makes it the best? Because it will save 30kb of bandwith? This solution is constrained in options, for example, if i want to take the user to the third textbox after the user press enter... what shoul i do? use enterindex... oh, it doesnt exist, but  in JS it would be extremly easy:

if (e.which == 9 || e.which == 13)

Comment: @IvanCastellanos: You shouldn't mess with browser's default behaviour. Many users are used to the fact that enter submits the form.

Comment: @IvanCastellanos This is not a chat so please stop spamming and beware I will maybe take my up-vote from your answer away if you continue spamming.

Comment: I dont care about your upvote. But your statement is true, this is not a chat.